# change screens in the same layout without using fragments

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing with Android Studio.
I created a screen that will have buttons on the side so it looks like a menu bar.
i want to make the left (red side) layout changeable - means that if i click on one of the images on the right (green side) the left layout will change to a different layout and will open a different activity.
I already have the activities and their layouts that i want to show on the left side using the clickable images on the right side.
can i make it work without using fragments?

[the "menu" i have and how i want it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79mwI.png)

the layout is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ightwall"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight=".7">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My List"

                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#D5D4D4"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight=".3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_mylist"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/freeadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_freetext"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_categorysearch"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favproductadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_favproduct"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace Fragment

in OnClickListener

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, new TargetFragment())
            .commit();
```

And Change yourxml at

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight=".7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My List"

            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

To

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight=".7">

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

  </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

create class TargetFragment.class

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 public class TargetFragment extends Fragment {
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.target_fragment_xml, container, false);

 // Enter code here
 return root;
 }
```

Comment: From the title I believe he doesnt want to use fragments

Comment: I'm trying to change everything into Fragments now...see if it will work..i have a question- what the layout target_fragment_xml should contain?

Comment: and another question is in the OnClickListener there is a : .replace(R.id.content_main.........what am i doing here-replacing what and to what? i would appreciate an explanation about that im doing , thank you ! :)

Comment: in the OnClickListener . You replace <FrameLayout> in activity_main.xml == target_fragment.xml

Comment: At target_fragment.xml is place you show screen new

Comment: can you give me an example i don't really understand what should i do if im changing between few screens ,i understand that on the onClickListener i have this: .replace(R.id.contentmain, new TargetFragment()).....for every imageView i have and on the TargetFragment.java i have that :  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_text_search, container, false
        return root;
    }

Comment: which the R.layout.activity_text_search is the new layout i want to show. but what if i want to add another layout from a different image view(for example R.layout.try) what im changing in TargetFragment.java?

Comment: means how do i know in which fragment im at in the TargetFragment.java?

Answer (score 0):

The better and easy way is to use fragments. However if you don't wan't to use fragments, then you can have all the views in your activity's xml in some separate relative or linear layout, whichever you prefer and play with hide-show views with each click.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use fragments. Fragments are designed to be reusable UI layouts. But if you don't want to use fragments, you can create CustomView and use `addView`, `removeView` like example:

```
LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(context);
layout.addView(new  Button(context));
layout.addView(new ImageButton(context));

TextView view = new TextView(context);
view.setText("Hello World");
layout.addView(view); 

layout.removeView(view);
```